# Utilizar ID como variável global é uma boa prática em JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, html, global

descobri que existe existe uma nova forma de resgatar e definir valores a uma tag HTML qualquer, utilizando seu ID como variável:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Meu Teste</title>
</head>

<body>

  <input id="testeVariavel">

</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
/*1- Utilizando o ID da TAG como variável*/
testeVariavel.value = "teste"


/*2- Forma tradicional*/
var testeVar = document.querySelector('#testeVariavel');
testeVar.value = "teste 2"
```

Gostaria de saber se é uma boa prática utilizar da primeira forma que exemplifico no código acima do JavaScript, pois vi que isso é bem mais prático que o método normal (uma vez que consigo trabalhar até mesmo com funções).

Ambos os jeitos demonstrados, consigo definir um valor qualquer para meu input, porém economizando no código e deixando "aparentemente" mais otimizado.

Tenho algum impacto futuro ao utilizar desta forma mais prática, pois é bem semelhante a uma variável global também, pois em teoria posso acessar o elemento sempre que eu quiser para definir ou resgatar um valor.

Comment: O ID foi feito para ancorar objetos, quando vc usa como tag, você está desvinculando do elemento ancorado, sendo assim, acredito que não tem a ver com boa ou ruim prática, mas qual o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acessar o elemento da primeira forma ([link da especificação](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object)) pode gerar alguns conflitos do tipo:

```js
console.log(typeof teste);
console.log(typeof (document.getElementById('teste')));
```

```html
<div id="teste"></div>
<script>
    function teste() { /* ... */ }
</script>
```

Veja que tanto o valor do id do elemento quanto a nome função são iguais. Isto poderá gerar bugs em sua aplicação visto que em um dado momento você esperaria que `teste` fosse uma referência ao elemento `div` e não a função. Veja que o problema não ocorre se você utilizar por exemplo o `getElementById`.

Este é um exemplo bem simples, mas imagine que um simples erro de digitação pode causar este tipo de conflito.

Um outro problema é com o antigo IE, que faz com que o valor do atributo `name` dos elementos dentro de um formulário sejam disponibilizados no `window`.

Então na minha opinião não é uma boa prática.

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcelo!
Sua explicação está bem completa, consegui compreender. Utilizando seu exemplo da digitação, faz todo sentido caso seja algo muito complexo que esteja em desenvolvimento e agora com essa explicação e link de exemplo de fato não vejo como uma boa prática utilizar este método mais simples.
Muito obrigado!